# I want to apply, to a whole column, a formula that is already an arrayformula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, string-formatting, array-formulas, google-query-language

I have a ledger with a bunch of expenses listed by date, category, and amount.
[Expenses ledger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Hus.png)

Separately I have an analytics sheet for one category, "Gas". I want the analytics sheet to show total gas expenditures month by month without having to update anything other than the ledger.
I can get a list of unique months with this formula:
`=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(YEAR('Main Ledger'!A2:A), MONTH('Main Ledger'!A2:A), 1)))`
This populates the months the way I want, and the list will automatically grow with the ledger. I put these in column A.

For each month, I want to compare every entry in the ledger against the date in column A and the category "Gas". I can do that for a single month with the following formula in column B:

`=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS('Main Ledger'!D$2:D,MONTH('Main Ledger'!A$2:A),MONTH(A2),YEAR('Main Ledger'!A$2:A),YEAR(A2),'Main Ledger'!F$2:F,"Gas"))`

[Gasoline analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOq6u.png)

Because I have to use arrayformula to make the date comparison on the ledger, I'm having trouble figuring out how to then use arrayformula to automatically apply this monster formula to all of column B. As column A grows (automatically because of `UNIQUE`, I want column B to grow too.

I do not want to prepopulate column B and have a bunch of zeroes lying around, mainly because I will be using columns A and B to populate a chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in one go:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A2:D}, 
 "select month(Col1),sum(Col4) 
  where Col4 is not null
  group by month(Col1) 
  label month(Col1)'month'")
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({TEXT(Sheet1!A2:A, "mmmm"), Sheet1!A2:D}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col5),month(Col2) 
  where Col5 is not null
  group by month(Col2),Col1 
  label Col1'month'"), 9^9, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: This gives exactly the data I want.
Next issue is I'm not sure how to make the month column present as "January, February ..." etc.

Comment: @NiusAtreides answer updated